# Navbar focusing on last part of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am unable to stop my navbar focusing on Contact, it should focus on the section of the webpage it is in, but it does not, and instead focuses on Contact. When I remove Contact, it focuses on the next last in the list which has the class page-scroll.

http://www.paddykeoghgoode.com/

I've been modifying my personal website lately and I've managed to make the top header always be active on the contact section of the site.

When inspecting element on the webpage the list class has contact as active which is what would normally make this sort of issue happen.

```
<li class="page-scroll active">
```

Though in my actual source code it looks like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="hidden">
      <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu">
      <a href="http://www.paddykeoghgoode.com/blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Which has no instance of this occurring. I believe this is related to the class page scroll, but can't isolate what is causing it to auto hover instead of hovering and focusing on the section of the page it is on.

I believe this to be the JS which is causing the issue, but amn't sure what to modify

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #1a242f;
```

I can change the background color to be anything, but as soon as I do that you can't hover over contact and it have the same effect as the rest of the items in the navbar.

Here is the freelancer.js which could be affecting it too:

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Freelancer Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.page-scroll a', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Floating label headings for the contact form
$(function() {
    $("body").on("input propertychange", ".floating-label-form-group", function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("floating-label-form-group-with-value", !! $(e.target).val());
     }).on("focus", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
         $(this).addClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
     }).on("blur", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
          $(this).removeClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
      });
 });

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
     target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

Comment: "I believe this to be the JS..." - The snippet you posted is CSS, not JS. I agree that JS is probably causing the issue somewhere along the way, as the class `active` is being added to your Contact link somewhere. Without seeing the JS, it's difficult to assist.

Comment: BTW your google analytic code should be added before the closing </head> tag, You have it starting before the <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">. Put it in the <head> section, Also check your code and fix the issues https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.paddykeoghgoode.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks! I've added some of the js now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no JS to handle changing the `active` class from one menu item to another.

Edit your scrolling function in `freelancer.js` file to something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.page-scroll a', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        $('.navbar-nav .active').removeClass('active');
        $anchor.closest('li').addClass('active');

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You could also add this to your css to prevent the site title from staying dark after clicking on it:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it still highlights contact as a default. My original code for that part is now included in the description.

Comment: That's because your `html` file has the `active` class on that element. Change it to `<li class="page-scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>`.

Comment: In the actual html it is like that, but it automatically chooses the last one as active on load.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, change `body` to this:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

That should fix the issue you were talking about.
I would also suggest the following changes:
Find and remove these from the bootstrap.min.css file
1. `, .nav>li>a:focus`
2. `,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus`
Add this to your freelance.css file
1. `.nav>li>a{ text-decoration: none;}`

Those are just suggestions though.